# Datatable loads mass data slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i have about 5000 records and load in datatable, but it takes a long time to load the data onto datatable.

i tried:

```
$('#usertable').dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength":50,
    "deferLoading": 5000,
});
```

and this:

```
$('#usertable').dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength":50,
    "deferRender": true
});
```

both are not working as the page loads very slow.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Loading _5000_ records at a time is _VERY BAD_ approach..Use pagination instead....

Comment: @RayonDabre datatable does the pagination already

Comment: you are using client side pagination. Use server side pagination, so at a time you will load 50 rows per page,

Comment: @JagsSparrow oh seems like i need to use a laravel-datatable library then. much more complicated

Comment: You can use datatables also,https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html